# EJS JavaScript SPA

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm wanting to build a single-page application using NodeJS and plain JavaScript so that it replicates what you can do with C# MVC and Kendo-UI's router.

I have the following on my index.ejs:

```html
<div id="views-users" hidden="hidden">
    <%- include('_search.ejs') %>
    <%- include('_create.ejs') %>
    <%- include('_update.ejs') %>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <h2><%= PageTitle %></h2>
    <div id="layout-users"></div>
</div>

<script>
    const router = {
        routes: {
            '#': () => {
                router.showIn('#view-users-search');
                modelUsersSearch.show();
            },
            '#/create': () => {
                router.showIn('#view-users-create');
                modelUsersCreate.show();
            },
            '#/update/:id': (id) => {
                modelUsersUpdate.id = id;
                router.showIn('#view-users-update');
                modelUsersUpdate.show();
            }
        },

        routeToRegex: route => {
            const escapedRoute = route.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
            const regexRoute = escapedRoute.replace(/:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/g, '([^/]+)');
            const finalRegex = `^${regexRoute}$`;

            return new RegExp(finalRegex);
        },
        showIn: viewSelector => {
            const layout = document.querySelector('#layout-users');
            const viewsContainer = document.querySelector('#views-users');
            const view = document.querySelector(viewSelector);
            if (layout.childNodes.length) {
                viewsContainer.append(...layout.childNodes);
            }
            layout.append(...view.childNodes);
        },

        change: () => {
            let hash = window.location.hash;
            if (!hash) {
                hash = '#';
            }
            if (hash === '#/') {
                hash = '#';
            }

            const routes = Object.keys(router.routes);
            const matchedRoute = routes.find(route => {
                const regexPattern = router.routeToRegex(route);
                const routeMatched = regexPattern.test(hash);
                return routeMatched;
            });
            if (!matchedRoute) {
                throw new Error(`Invalid route: ${hash}`);
            }

            const action = router.routes[matchedRoute];
            action();
        }
    };

    // routing events
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
        router.change();
    });
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(ev) {
        router.change();
    });
</script>
```

And the following in one of my "partials" (_search.ejs):

```html
<div id="view-users-search">
    <h2 class="h4">Search Users</h2>
    <div id="table-users"></div>
</div>

<script>
    const modelUsersSearch = {
        hasInit: false,

        init: () => {
            if (modelUsersSearch.hasInit) {
                return;
            }
            modelUsersSearch.hasInit = true;

            const datatable = utilities.initializeDataTable('#table-users', {
                columns: [
                    {
                        select: 3,
                        type: 'date',
                        format: 'YYYY/DD/MM hh:mm:ss',
                        sort: 'desc'
                    }
                ],
                data: {
                    headings: ['Full Name', 'Username', 'Email', 'Created', 'Status'],
                    data: [
                        [
                            // data retracted
                        ],
                        [
                            // data retracted
                        ],
                        [
                            // data retracted
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            });
        },
        show: () => {
            modelUsersSearch.init();
        }
    };
</script>
```

This works great on initial load, but if I navigate to a separate SPA route and then back to the search SPA route, the DOM in my layout is empty which leads me to believe that I'm losing my DOM when moving it from the layout to the hidden container but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Please (re?)read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". The current title is just a bunch of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Heretic Monkey's comment about forum etiquette wasn't enough to solve my problem. Fortunately after a little more debugging I found the issue.

The issue was that my `showIn` method had the following line:

```js
layout.append(...view.childNodes);
```

This had the side effect of only copying over the view's children rather than the view itself. So I was losing the parent container when moving the content to the layout which mean the next time it went to grab the parent container, there wasn't any children.

To resolve this issue I simply changed that one line to:

```js
layout.append(view);
```